# calloc sometimes gives double the amount of memory asked

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I came across something I don't understand why and I'd like to hear an explanation about it.
I have this struct:

```
typedef struct Student {
    int age;
    char *name;
} Student;

int main()
{
    Student **test1 = calloc(2, sizeof(*test1));
    Student **test2 = calloc(2, sizeof(**test2));
    return 0;
}
```

I've noticed that test1 gets 2 memory allocations (as it should) while test2 gets 4. Why is that and which is the correct usage? I assume its the first one but i'm not sure why.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have one asterisk in front of test1 and two in front of test2 in your sizeof calls?

Comment: First, how do you know?  Second, is there a reason you are using two star pointers?

Comment: How do you know that _calloc sometimes gives double the amount of memory asked_? You program does not show anything.

Comment: I noticed that by tracking the pointers on debugging mode. As for the usage, its relevant for my progrem. This is just an example.

Comment: So is your actual question: _"why is the value of `sizeof(*test1)`  different from the value of `sizeof(**test2)` "_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(*test1)` is the size of a pointer `Student*`, while `sizeof(**test)` is the size of a structure `Student`.The structure has a pointer, so its size should be larger than the size of a pointer.

```
Student **test1 = calloc(2, sizeof(*test1));
```

Is the typical usage. This is allocating 2-element array of `Student*` and assigning the pointer to its first element to `test1`.

Answer (score 3):

Two things here:

1. You're allocating two different amounts of memory here.  In the first case, you allocate space for 2 objects of type `Student *`, while in the second case you allocate space for 2 objects of type `Student`.  The latter is likely larger than the former, so you'll be able to put more object of type `Student *` there.
2. You don't show how you're verifying how much memory you've gotten, but it's [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to read or write past the bounds of allocated memory.  Your program might crash, or it might not.

Comment: I just noticed that while debugging when I added watchers to *(test+1), *(test+2),... I saw how many 'cells' are null after calloc. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(*test)` is a size in bytes of the pointer to `Student`. It will be on most systems 4 or 8.

`sizeof(**test)`gives you the size of the `Student`. The allocation (test2) makes no sense at all.

You can easily test it yourself by printing the sizes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct Student {
    int age;
    char *name;
    double somedata[100];
} Student;

int main()
{
    Student **test1;
    Student **test2;

    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(*test1));
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(**test2));
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/W6e8YzKKf